# c# xamarin get an Unauthorized access exception while write in usb storage

Tags: c#, xamarin

i want to write a byte in file in usb storage,
but i get an Unauthorized access exception.
how can i solved this?

```
    UsbReciever usbReciever = new UsbReciever();
    usbManager = (UsbManager) GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);
    device = null;
    PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    RegisterReceiver(usbReciever, filter);

    if (usbManager != null)
    {
        foreach (var dev in usbManager.DeviceList)
        {
            device = dev.Value;
        }
        usbManager.RequestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        bool hasPermision = usbManager.HasPermission(device);
        UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.OpenDevice(device);
    }

    try
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("/storage/3ACB-22BF/cntl",FileMode.Open);
        fileStream.Seek(1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        fileStream.WriteByte(cmd);
    }
```

in this line,

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("/storage/3ACB-22BF/cntl",FileMode.Open);
```

get an Unauthorized access exception.

Comment: You need to request permission. Read this: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbManager.HasPermission/p/Android.Hardware.Usb.UsbDevice/